# free pointer to pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm not familiar with C as much as with C++ but I found my self in need to debug
C application and after even succeeded to do so, but I'm not sure if my fix
indeed is correct.

Here is a code:

```
FcValueList **value = NULL;
value = (FcValueList **) malloc (SIZEOF_VOID_P * nobjs);

// other code...

if (value)
free (value);
```

The **FcValueList** is a structure and **SIZEOF_VOID_P** is a size of
void pointer.
The above code does not work because the **value** is "unable to read memory"

So I applied following fix and the code worked with app exiting with 0:

```
value = (FcValueList **) malloc (SIZEOF_VOID_P * nobjs);

// other code...

if (*value)
free (value);
```

Is my fix correct? and if not what would be correct then?

Comment: You don't need to typecast the return value of `malloc` in a C program.

Comment: This code doesn't make sense; if you need to store `FcValueList*`, you should use `sizeof(FcValueList*)`, not the size of a void pointer.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: @Oliver SIZEOF_VOID_P is set by configure script, I would need to change a lot of code then.

Comment: You should do, because it's semantically incorrect as it stands ;)

Comment: Chances are very high that `sizeof(void *)` is the same as `sizeof(FcValueList *)` on your platform. Don't sweat it too much.

Comment: Hopefully `//other code...` starts with `if (value) {`

Comment: @CarlNorum: That's not the only reason though.  I'd argue that the above code is confusing to the reader/maintainer, because the types don't match, thus obscuring the intent.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - absolutely, and I agree. But sometimes you're working with a 3rd party project and it's not worth the effort.

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc (and friends)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845). Also, `SIZEOF_VOID_P` is painful. Use `sizeof *value` there instead.

Comment: Thank you guys for response, suggestion from Carl solved everything.

Comment: Sometimes readability gets better if you write a typedef or a few. Here, e.g. ``typedef FcValueList* FcValueListPtr`` would result in less unusual code and probably less confusion. In combination with a better name for value: ``FcValueListPtr * valuePointers; valuePointers = malloc(sizeof(FcValueListPtr) * nobjs );``

Comment: @user2225104, I completely disagree with ever hiding a `*` inside a typedef like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, your fix is not correct. Your original code is fine, but doesn't need the `if` statement. Passing a `NULL` pointer to `free()` is allowed.

Without more explanation, it's not really possible to give more context - your first code example is fine as shown.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked, and I even learned something :) I can accept your answer in 7 minutes...